# bind angle in rotatetransform WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some code:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
     <RotateTransform CenterX="50" CenterY="-10" Angle="45" />
  </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@TestingAngle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there any way to bind the angle property of a rendertransform to a value?
Is there any construction like:

```
<RotateTransform CenterX="50" CenterY="-10" Angle="{Binding XPath=@TestingAngle}" />
```

Is it possible to do without usage of the code-behind file(using only XAML)?

The value TestingAngle should be taken from the following code:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TestData">
      <x:XData>
        <Information TestingAngle="30"/>
      </x:XData>
  </XmlDataProvider>
```

Is there any way to write a construnction like:

```
                        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding XPath=@TestingAngle}"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course. Bind to a regular view model property (e.g. `MyAngle`) like `Angle="{Binding Path=MyAngle}"`, or shorter `Angle="{Binding MyAngle}"`.

Comment: I'm not very good at WPF. Could u please explain what's view model property?

Comment: You should make yourself familiar with the basic concepts of WPF. Read about data binding in the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN, and search the web for `MVVM`, which is the common architectural pattern used in WPF applications.

Comment: Depends if you want to observe changes - you could just bind to nothing and provide a `fallbackvalue` in the binding. If you want to observe some sort of change in the value, you will need a data context (a viewmodel usually)

Comment: I have the constant value(rotation angle) and I need to bind this value to the angle property of RotateTransform. So I guess I do not need to observe the changes.

Comment: @EaterOfCode Vandalism and then rollback.

Comment: @truel Stop vandalizing your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a resource within your XAML file and bind to that...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <System:Double x:Key="AngleResource">-3</System:Double>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then bind to it...

```
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{DynamicResource AngleResource}"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        </StackPanel>
```

If it isn't going to update, adding it as a resource really only gives you reuse - so you can share this angle with other elements and update a single source.

Comment: Actually I get the value from XMlDataProvider - something like      <Page.Resources>
      <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TestData">
          <x:XData>
   <Information TestingAngle="30"/>
          </x:XData>
      </XmlDataProvider>  
</Page.Resources>

Comment: Sorry, I didn't asked clearly. Is there a way to write construnction like:                             <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding XPath=@TestingAngle}"/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

Comment: The getting value is not a problem. The problem is to bind the value from xml to the angle.

Comment: `<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Source={StaticResource ConfigurationData}, XPath=/Config/angle}"/>`

Assumes you have an XmlDataProvider called ConfigurationData

Comment: Your welcome - sorry it took be a couple of reads to understand the problem :)